# Ask facebook to re-scrape URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The og:image of the website has been changed recently. The site contains more than 100 pages, each containing their individual og:image. How can i ask or force facebook to re-scrape all the pages, so that the image gets updated? Using the facebook debugger tool will be too tedious task. Until facebook re-scrape's the site, i won't be able to submit collection for the app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two alternatives here in your situation

1. As per ysrb's answer loop through list of your URLs with the Open Graph Debugger tool
2. Or wait patiently for 30 days until Facebook re-scrapes your Pages as it says in documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#scraperinfo)

> Why and when does Facebook scrape my website?
>
> Facebook needs to scrape links shared to Facebook to know which to link preview information to show on Facebook.com or on Facebook for iOS and Android. This happens every 30 days to ensure the properties are up to date. The linked page is also scraped when the URL is entered into the Debugger Tool.
>
> Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference. However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your page every 30 days.

Comment: @ChrisHoughton - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#scraperinfo (as of 2015.04.08)

Comment: This is no longer correct. There is an API endpoing that Doug and others explain in another answer.

Comment: my pages were scraped last time in 2012, and now im doing all of them manually :(

Answer (score 34):

You can force a re-scrape via API, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#update:

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

(But if you don’t have a real list of the affected URLs, this is kinda moot. Then you only can wait until it happens automatically, I guess.)

Comment: This is great. The response includes the refreshed OG data as well, so you can check it yourself while scraping.

Comment: This is the true answer and should be the chosen one. shame the other one is, since it's not even an answer at all.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer.  POSTing /?id=<url>&scrape=true to https://graph.facebook.com/ will force a re-scrape of the og tags for hte url.  One must remember that this must be a POST request, not a GET request, otherwise you just get the number of shares.  And if you add another parameter called callback=<somecallbackfunction>, you can do this via an AJAX JSONP request within the browser, and no need to tie up your server.

Comment: Hi , can this method be used to update dynamically created meta tags using javascript?

ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868686/react-meta-tags-not-working-for-facebook

Comment: @HaswinVidanage the answer to that question over there ... well, already answers that.

Answer (score 5):

```
       $config = array(
            "appId" => 'APP_ID',
            "secret" => 'APP_SECRET');

        $fb = new Facebook($config);
        $r=$fb->api('/','POST',array(
            'id'=>PAGE_URL,
            'scrape'=>'true'
        ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that Facebook requires the parameters be passed via `POST`. Facebook just ignores `GET` requests.

Here is the code in C#.

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/?id="
    + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.example.com/index.html")
    + "&scrape=true");
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responsestream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responsestream != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader bodyreader = new StreamReader(responsestream))
            {
                string fbResp = bodyreader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

curl --insecure "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=[YOUR-URL-TO-SCRAPE]&scrape=true"

curl should be ssl capable (as it is https://graph...)

Comment: I got this to work, thanks a lot. -  You need to be sure to set the user agent, or else FB will decide not to honor the scrape request, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can try loop from the list of url and do

```
curl "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=$url"
```

Comment: Ok. The exact list of url is unknown. Approx there are 310 urls as of now. Manually specifying each of them for the loop will be time consuming and we may  miss some url due to humman error

Comment: You must have some kind of sitemap.xml or something. Even if it's static files, you can list it and create the url

Comment: Tested - This method does not work.

Comment: @GTCrais what do you mean doesn't work? What's the test case?

Comment: @ysrb I mean I tried it, and it doesn't work, probably because you can't access that URL without being logged into facebook. The data doesn't get scrapped by facebook with this method.