# Facebook comments in dreamweaver

Tags: html, facebook

Please, I will really need your kind assistance here. This is what I am trying to achieve: on my news website, there is (for example) a URL - nigerianobservernews.com/15082013/news/news1.html. On this URL, the title and the content changes on a daily basis. I want to know how I can use facebook comment in such a way that the comment on yesterday's article on that same URL will be different on the comment on today's article even though the page/url is the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to **scrape** your page to refresh Facebook's internal cache.

To scrap you can send a web request to the [Facebook Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and pass your URL, or you can do like this:

```
curl "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=$url"
```

[Also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352467):

> When does Facebook scrape my page?
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
> the site. Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the
> properties are up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for
> the Open Graph page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered
> into the Facebook URL Debugger. Facebook observes cache headers on
> your URLs - it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of
> preference. However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will
> scrape your page every 24 hours.