# React meta tags not working for Facebook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, meta-tags

I have clone the app https://github.com/alanbsmith/react-node-example and try to use the [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). By inspecting the browser I can see the meta tags values are present but when I post the URL on Facebook and try to see the meta tag status here, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ It says The properties should be passed.
Please anyone can suggest whats going wrong here.

Please find my component code,

```
import '../assets/stylesheets/base.scss';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet
            htmlAttributes={{"lang": "en", "amp": undefined}} // amp takes no value
            title="My Title"
            titleTemplate="React Helmet - %s"
            defaultTitle="React Helmet Title"
            base={{"target": "_blank", "href": "http://myappname.herokuapp.com/"}}
            meta={[
                {"name": "description", "content": "Helmet application"},
                {"property": "fb:app_id", "content": "myfbid"},
                {"property": "og:title", "content": "My application title goes here."},
                {"property": "og:type", "content": "website"},
                {"property": "og:url", "content": "http://myappname.com/"},
                {"property": "og:image", "content": "https://imagename.png"},
                {"property": "og:description", "content": "Application description"},
                {"property": "og:site_name", "content": "MyAppname.com"},

            ]}
          />
          <h1>Welcome to the React helmet App, {this.props.name}!</h1>
        </div>  
    )
  }
};
export default App;
```

Comment: When the page loads, maybe the script hasn't been initialized yet. If you make your app Universal (or Isomorphic) then it should be there on page load.

Answer (score 4):

That's because Facebook's Page **scraper** doesn't execute javascript (unlike Google's Page **Scraper**, I believe). This means you need to pre-process and add the meta-tags on the server side.

In Chrome you can see exactly what your server is returning by using `view-source`

```
view-source:http://example.com
```

Comment: I am already using server side rendering using react-helmet but still am facing the same issue. Please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/247

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netlify for your deployments, there is a setting you can enable in your build & deploy called "prerendering". I enabled this setting, and within 2 minutes, it fixed my issue. I'm guessing other deployment services may have similar settings. If not, (http://prerender.io)[http://prerender.io] is an option as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).