# Ask facebook to re-scrape URL automatically

Tags: facebook

how can I make a php code for facebook to automatically update the cache of a single url
I saw something similar in other threads, but did not manage to make it work:

[Is there an API to force Facebook to scrape a page again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again)

[Ask facebook to re-scrape URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351980/ask-facebook-to-re-scrape-url?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! The first link has a clear description of a POST request that would achieve this. What have you tried so far? What exactly do you mean by "did not manage to make it work". Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I answered below, because the characters did not reach me

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding these details as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example use this php code, adding the url of my web www.tolchx.net, but it still appears the same GIF when I go to debugging:

```
<?php
   try {
      $params = [
         'id' => 'https://www.tolchx.net',
         'scrape' => 'true',
      ];
      $response = $fb->post('/', $params);
      print_r($response);
   } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
?>
```

With that enough to automatically update the link cache www.tolchx.net?

thanks for the reply