# Thumbnail image on Facebook can't be uploaded, neither do the metatags work

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm having an issue concerning the thumbnail from a web page that is being shared on socials (LinkedIn & Facebook). LinkedIn has an easy way to choose whatever image you want as a thumbnail, but Facebook is not working for me as it should even if I upload the desired image as one of the available images.

[The first 5 are automatically generated, the 6th is uploaded. I'm unable to only select the uploaded image, the one I desire to use as a stand-alone thumbnail image.][1]

I've tried to add the desired image to the og metatags (drupal 8), but it still doens't load the right image.

Where should I look further into to find a solution? The metatags on our website or Facebook's uploading system?

Thanks in advance for any help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFhI9.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't appear to be a programming question so it may be more appropriate for Super User or possibly Server Fault. If this is programming related, try to include some snippets of the code you tried along with what happened, and what you were expecting.

Comment: Please try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352467/5668919, if it would help and also try validating the page here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/